# Memory profiling WPF gives increase in WeakReference

Tags: wpf

I am running a memry profiler on my WPF app. I leave the profiler turned on and keep the app on too. But I donot touch the app. With time the System.WeakReference is consuming memory gradually. Not sure how to correct this scenario!

My app has multiple tabs with xceed datagrid on each tab and data is displayed on the grids. There is a continuos connection to changing prices coming from third party sources, and we update the existing rows with the prices by updating the underlying model. Its a MVVM pattern code with Prism to populate the tabs.

Heres a snapshot:
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information about what is happening with your application. Maybe it reads the data from somewhere? Maybe it has some timers running? A short example reproducing the said behaviour might be useful, too.

Comment: Prism intensively uses `WeakReference`s, for example in `PubSubEvent`s, `DelegateCommand`s and `CompositeCommand`s. What are the memory consumption statistics (in MB)?

Comment: http://paulstovell.com/blog/weakevents this link might help you to get rid off from this issue...

Comment: Try different memory profiling tools; there are many on the market, google for them. They will show you exactly who is creating what, and who is holding all the references alive, and why.

Comment: Is there a free one? Can you please point me to one?

Answer (score 2):

[`WeakReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=vs.110).aspx) instances should, dare I say, never be a concern for memory consumption.. They are a special type in .Net, and GC will collect objects referenced using `WeakReference` in case it detects memory pressure. Applications like WPF and the like (XAML based, Silverlight for example) tend to have high use of `WeakReference` type, because these frameworks by design use them in many places. (A comment to this question also lists `Prism` - although I personally don't know enough about `Prism`).

From the documentation -
"**A weak reference allows the garbage collector to collect an object while still allowing an application to access the object.**"

If you have any concern with memory consumption (are you seeing real issues with memory consumtion.. for example `OutOfMemoryException`?), **you need to look elsewhere**.. otherwise, per my knowledge, instances of `WeakReference` cannot be not an issue by design.

Comment: Each weak reference itself consumes 16 bytes of memory .. so as they pile up atleast 16 bytes is lost fo every additional weak reference created. Huge amount of memory consumption doesnt mean out of memory always, it leads to slow performance of apps.

Comment: @Debdeep Sure it takes some memory... every object does.. but it is not necessarily a bad thing.. I respectfully disagree with making a general statement that huge amount of memory consumption leads to slow performance.. There are plenty of apps which are designed to work with huge amounts of memory and yet be fastest.. SQL Server for example. It can in some cases, and hence may need tuning.. but that doesn't seem to be case here. All OP is saying is that he sees increasing number of WeakReferences

Comment: So you agree that memory leak is there. But you say I should not worry about it? I am sure I can introduce some data structures to make the app run faster .. But I am only interested in fixing this memory leak as over a few hours the app starts consuming 5 to 6 gigs and I have noticed its mostly weak references that have added so much memory consumption.

Comment: After closely looking at the screenshot you have (with squinty eyes.. SO needs to do better at displaying screenshots), my guess would be that you could have some binding related issue. Common trap for such applications. Search the net for the same.. FYI, I came across this, which may or may not be applicable - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micmcd/archive/2008/03/07/avoiding-a-wpf-memory-leak-with-databinding-black-magic.aspx Also look at this - http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls

Comment: @VikasGupta: Hint: If you use the Chrome browser at least you can right-click any image and do 'Open image in new tab', which will usually give you an uncompressed, easier to read view of the posted image.

Comment: FWIW, I agree in principle that a large number of weak references shouldn't generally be a concern, but it does seem odd (off) that some part of the application (Xceed, most likely) should keep manufacturing new ones without getting rid of others (which - it seems - should now be stale, assuming this is database-related).

Comment: So basically there is no solution as I assumed when I had put this question up for bounty .. I have also written to xceed with a simple grid in which too I see this leak.